# MAX in PHP returning wrong value

Tags: php

I have an array with key and value pair. I'm building this array dynamically and below is the code.

```
$x[] = array('type_name' => $value->name,
            'percentage'=> intval($percentage));
```

My intention is to get the maximum value and for that I do

```
max($x);
```

However it is returning the wrong value actually the lowest value. Following is my array. Any help would be awesome.

```
$x = array(
array( 
    'type_name' => 'type 1'
    'percentage' => 10,

),
array(
    'type_name' => 'type 2'
    'percentage' => 15,

),
array(
    'type_name' => 'type 3'
    'percentage' => 45,
),
);
```

Thanks is advance.

Comment: Please show sample data. I don't duck a simple built in would actually be broken.

Comment: Show us the result of `var_dump($x)` before you use `max()` and show us what you actually are getting. You say you're getting the wrong value, but we have no idea if that's actually the case.

Comment: And this has something to do with MySQL?

Comment: Guys, I'm really sorry for not giving the array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From php [max() documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.max.php) :

> // Multiple arrays of the same length are compared from left to right

It means that if you want to compare "percentage" values first instead of "type_name" values, you'll have to change their order in the array.

So, you could build your array like this ("percentage" comes first) and it should work :

```
$x[] = array(
    'percentage'=> intval($percentage),
    'type_name' => $value->name
);
```

For example :

```
$x = array(
    array( 
        'percentage' => 10,
        'type_name' => 'type 1'
    ),
    array(
        'percentage' => 15,
        'type_name' => 'type 2'
    ),
    array(
        'percentage' => 45,
        'type_name' => 'type 3'
    ),
    array(
        'percentage' => 25,
        'type_name' => 'type 4'
    )
);

print_r(max($x));
```

Output :

> ```
> Array
> (
>     [percentage] => 45
>     [type_name] => type 3
> )
> ```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 2):

You are creating an array of arrays. `max` doesn’t know that your arrays should be compared by the `'percentage'` key, so it can’t be used here.

Instead, find the maximum value yourself. For example, like this:

```
$maxPercentage = false;
foreach ($x as $item) {
  if ($maxPercentage === false || $item['percentage'] > $maxPercentage) {
    $maxPercentage = $item['percentage'];
  }
}
```

Now, `$maxPercentage` will store maximum percentage. Of, if you want an item with maximum percentage, get it like this:

```
$maxPercentage = false;
$maxItem = false;
foreach ($x as $item) {
  if ($maxPercentage === false || $item['percentage'] > $maxPercentage) {
    $maxPercentage = $item['percentage'];
    $maxItem = $item;
  }
}
```

Comment: I didn't even notice that the OP actually is creating a multi dimensional array. Good catch.

Answer (score 2):

You need to read how the `max` compares against different types of data. In your case, you are trying to compare against one of the array item i.e. `percentage` inside one of the item so the function `max` does not know to do this.

There is an example by Revo in the [manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.max.php#115211) which shows you how to do this.